# No such file or directory message

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I get next error when trying open http://localhost:5000/

**Error:**

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
>   'C:\Users\Andriixyz\Desktop\chat- node\chat\client\build\index.html'

```
const path = require("path");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(port);
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("client"));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/client/build/index.html"));
});
```

Comment: Yes, it happens some time if you does not open or run a file for long time. You just do one thing rename the folder and project name in package.json file and then restart the server. I think it will work for you

Comment: It did not help :(

Comment: Once check that your project directory "/client/build/index.html" file is there. I think that is the error which is throwing by the node.

Comment: try a console.log, see if the correct route is being printed

Comment: if you mean console.log (__ dirname);, then output the correct path. C:\Users\Andriixyz\Desktop\chat- node\chat\

Comment: Okay does this dir `C:\Users\Andriixyz\Desktop\chat- node\chat\` has sub folders called `/client/build` and `build` folder has `index.html` file ?

Comment: No, dir has not sub folders called /client/build